# fastlane "Your session has expired. Please log in."

Tags: match, app-store-connect, fastlane, apple-developer

When using fastlane match I get the error "Your session has expired. Please log in."
The app_store_connect_api_key seems fine and does not expire normally. WHat is this problem about?

Answer (score 3):

What solved this for me was:

1. Opening the Flutter iOS project in XCode
2. Select the target "Runner" in the project pane
3. Click "Signing & Capabilities"
4. Sign in with my AppleID

Answer (score 0):

I had also to sign multiple pods for this to work.

In XCode check the Pods tab and look for those with a "lego" brick logo (bundle). If you have those, you'll have to go to "Signing & Capabilities" and sign them too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What solved for me:

1. Go to Xcode -> Settings -> Accounts
2. Log in

Answer (score -1):

The app_store_connect_api_key is alright. A login to https://developer.apple.com/account solved this.

Comment: did not work for me